# Classification of finite groups of order $p^3qr$ up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

Does there exist a reference which aims to solve this or a similar problem? For distinct primes $p,q,r$. The closest thing I found was a paper classifying groups of order $p^2qr$. From a cursorary glance it seems to use Burnside transfer theorem which I've never seen before so I wasn't sure if it could be modified for this case.

I was curious about this problem as it came up when I was trying to count groups upto isomorphism of order $2024=2^3\cdot 11 \cdot 23$.

Weirdly enough GAP didn't have an entry for it in SmallGroups. But running FiniteGroupCount[2024] on Mathematica returned a result of 46. So 43 non abelian groups.

2024 in particular is small enough that I didn't need to consider extensions of Alternating or Lie type groups. So maybe it could be a subset of all possible semi direct products between the underlying cyclic groups? But that seems very loosey goosey. Since I know extensions need not be semi direct products.

Comment: Please link to that paper.

Comment: Your factorization of $2024$ is inaccurate!

Comment: $23$ is a prime divisor of $2024$. The page by [Max Horn](http://groups.quendi.de/?order_min=2024&order_max=2024) gives the number of groups as well, and a few more details (like $5$ nilpotent groups and $41$ solvable non-nilpotent ones).

Comment: Oops that was a typo I meant to write 23 not 13 fixed it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there is no complete classification of groups of order $p^3qr$. There is a [2022 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.02933) by Dietrich, Eick and Pan with a complete and detailed classification of group whose orders have at most four prime factors, and they say at the end that they plan to do $p^4q$ next.

Classifying groups of order $2024$ would be tedious, but not too hard. Such a group is a semidirect product of a normal Sylow $23$-subgroup and a group of order $88$. So you just need to look at homomorphisms from groups of order $88$ to ${\rm Aut}(C_{23}) \cong C_{22}$.

Comment: Thanks! The paper you linked seems to be a good place to start, it looks very dense. 

Just for a sanity check. The semi direct product notion for the 2024 case you mentioned is due to 24-sylow subgroup being normal so it implies the Burnside theorem for existence of the p-complement right?

Comment: There is no such thing as a $24$-Sylow subgroup. You need the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem, not Burnside's Theorem, for the existence of a subgroup of order $88$.

Comment: I see thanks for your help I'll mark this as accepted. (Meant to type 23 there)